# Need help on spark analysis for 1 billion data

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I need to analyze 1 billion (100GB+) data using spark sql and persist in to mongo db or elastic search.

Source is RDBMS. We will fetch 1 billion (100GB+) data from RDBMS (Sql Server or oracle) column by column (analyze only one column at a time).

In analysis process i will perform group by on specific column, apply some udf transformations on group by output and persist it into target databases (Mongo DB or Elastic search)

configured spark cluster with 3 slaves:
Spark Version: 2.1.0
Cluster type: Stand alone.

Master Configuration:
Operating System: Cent OS 7
Processor Type: i5
Cores: 4
RAM: 16 GB

Slave Configuration:
Operating System: Cent OS 7
Processor Type: i5
Cores: 4
RAM: 16 GB

spark submit command:

`spark-submit --class com.poc.Client --master spark://datanode1:7077 --num-executors 9 --executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 9G  "AnalysisPOC-1.0.jar"`

```
conf.set("spark.shuffle.compress", "false");
conf.set("spark.broadcast.compress", "true");
conf.set("spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.compressed", "true");
conf.set("spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.batchSize", "10000");
conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
conf.set("spark.kryo.referenceTracking", "false");
conf.set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer", "4000");
conf.set("spark.io.compression.codec", "org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec");
```

**Reading form spark**:
Dataset columnDataset = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").options(sourceDbProps).load().groupBy("someColumnName").count().persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK());

**Writing to mongodb**:
MongoSpark.write(columnDataset).options(props).mode(SaveMode.Append).save();

Before submitting 1 Billion data i tested my code as follows:
Case - 1:
Columns: 7
Dataset: 500k
Status: success
Spark job time:
   Mongo DB: 6 mins 15 secs
   Elastic Search: 8 mins 25 secs

Case - 2:
Columns: 7
Dataset: 1 million
Status: success
Spark job time:
   Mongo DB: 13 mins 50 secs
   Elastic Search: 20 mins 30 secs

Case - 3:
Columns: 7
Dataset: 10 million
Status: success
Spark job time:
   Mongo DB: 50 mins 10 secs
   Elastic Search: 1 Hr 5 mins 4 secs

Case - 4:
Columns: 7
Dataset: 100 million
Status: failed
Spark job time:
   Mongo DB: Failed
   Elastic Search: Failed
Exceptions: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 192.168.1.70, executor 0): java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no space for new record

I need help to tune the spark job in efficient way and my job must process 1 billion data.

I need help to fetch rdbms data as fast as possible with out partition key. because i will analyze only one column at a time.

Comment: I think you ran out of disk space : ` There is no space for new record`

Comment: If you will try to load 1Billion rows of 1 column from RDBMS w/o partition key then data will be loaded slowly and only one executor, in this case one core of local system will try to load all data, which seems to be difficult, just like mentioned in this article - https://blog.knoldus.com/2017/02/09/partition-aware-data-loading-in-spark-sql/

Comment: Hello zhiro, Will you please suggest how i overcome There is no space for new record